# Insertion into Hive table

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive, logfiles

I am a newbie to hadoop. please help me out.

I have a log file which keeps on updating, I need to store this log file into a table in hive.Is it possible to add the new row that are generated in the logfile into this table when ever I want or at regular intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Hive support insert statement, so it should be possible. In the same time - I will not recommend this way of working with hive. I would assume that we speak about serious flow of logs - otherwise we would not use Hive. 
Hive is superior in data loading speed when we simply copy additional file to some HDFS directory which is defined as Hive's external table 
So my suggestion to use log rotate (or other technique) to create new files each X minutes or Y megabytes and then simply copy them into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really supported well by Hive. I would suggest looking into using Flume to store the log file into HDFS, and then have the Hive table simply point to that location and use an appropriate SerDe to access it.

Either that, or rotate the log file, and only store it into Hive once it is completely done being written to.